# How do I use the same view with two different forms and don’t loose the data provided by the user with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a form with several input fields about a meeting.

```
@app.route('/Alt_Reuniao/<WCodigoChaveP>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def Alt_Reuniao(WCodigoChaveP):

    # This function returns a list with de data from the Database about a specific meeting

    WReuniao = Executa_Query_Leitura("0005", WCodigoChaveP, "O")

    if not WReuniao:

        flash('Error.......')

        return redirect(url_for('Cad_Reunioes'))

    else:

        if WReuniao[8]:

            # this function returns a list with de data from the Database about the topic of the meeting 

            WAssunto = Executa_Query_Leitura("0002", WReuniao[8], "O")


        Wform = Cad_Reunioes_Form()

        if request.method == "POST":

            if Wform.validate():

                # save the data ......

                return redirect(url_for('Cad_Reunioes'))

            else:

                for Werro in Wform.errors.values():

                    flash(Werro[0])

                return render_template('Reuniao.html', Wformulario=Wform)

        else:

            Wform.WCPO_Reuniao.data = WReuniao[1]

            Wform.WCPO_Desc_Reuniao.data = WReuniao[2]

            Wform.WCPO_Nro_Part.data = WReuniao[3]

            Wform.WCPO_Cod_Assunto.data = WReuniao[8]

            if WReuniao[8]:

                if WAssunto:

                    Wform.WCPO_Assunto.data = WAssunto[1]


            return render_template('Reuniao.html', Wformulario=Wform)
```

This is my Reuniao.html template:

```
{% extends "Base_Cad_2.html" %}

{% block dados %}

    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Reuniao.label(id="WCPO_Reuniao", class="lab1") }} {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Reuniao(size = 100, maxlength=30, id="WCPO_Reuniao") }}

    <p id="PL"> {{ Wformulario.WCPO_L_Desc_Reuniao(id="WCPO_L_Desc_Reuniao", class="lab1") }} </p>

    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Desc_Reuniao(rows=5, cols=100, id="WCPO_Desc_Reuniao") }}

    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part.label(id="WCPO_Nro_Part", class="lab1") }} {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(size = 5, id="WCPO_Nro_Part") }}

    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Cod_Assunto.label(id="WCPO_Cod_Assunto", class="lab1") }} {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Cod_Assunto(size=10, readonly='readonly', id="WCPO_Cod_Assunto") }}

    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Assunto.label(id="WCPO_Assunto", class="lab1") }} {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Assunto(size=95, readonly='readonly', id="WCPO_Assunto") }}

    <button id="Selec_Assunto" name="Selec_Assunto" value="Selec_Assunto" type="button"> <a class="botoes" href="{{ url_for('Selec_Assuntos_Inicio', WRotChama = "001", WCodorig = Wformulario.WCPO_Cod_Reuniao ) }}" hreflang="pt-br"> Seleciona </a> </button>

{% endblock %}

{% block botoes %}

    <button id="gravar" name="gravar" value="Gravar" type="submit" class="botoes" > Gravar </button>

{% endblock %}
```

Basically, this view works fine.

When I select a meeting from a list in a previous template the view method is a GET and the data from the database is passed to the form and the template renders correctly.

When the method is a POST the data from the form is saved correctly in the Database,…

On the form there is a button Selec_Assunto. When the user click on that button I point to a view witch renders a template with a list of all possible topics for the meeting. These topics come from the database. There can be a lot of them so I can’t just use a combo. That’s why I use a template.

When the user select an topic from the list I have to render Alt_Reuniao view again and I have to pass to the view the selected topic.

This is working fine.

My problem is this: the method again is a GET. If before hitting the Selec_Assunto button the user alter or input data on the other fields in the form I loose these data from the user when the topic is selected. The view render the template with the data from the database again.

Everything seems to be working fine. I just want to maintain the data the user already change in the form before clicking on the Selec_Assunto button.

As you can see I’m new in Web developing, Python, Flask,…

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could update the "Selec_Assunto" button behavior to post the form data back to the server, but also include a redirect variable. When the redirect variable is included, the server would save the form changes and then redirect to the "Selec_Assuntos_Inicio" view, whereas it would follow the previous/normal form posting behavior if the redirect variable isn't present. For example:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        if Wform.validate():

            # save the data ……

            if Wform.redirect.data:
                return redirect(Wform.redirect.data)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('Cad_Reunioes'))

        else:

            for Werro in Wform.errors.values():
                flash(Werro[0])

            return render_template('Reuniao.html', Wformulario=Wform)
```

It's worth noting that this approach requires you to use JavaScript to override the "Selec_Assunto" button behavior (as you'd be forcing it to perform a form submission essentially). Here's one way you could do that using jQuery:

```
$('button#Selec_Assunto').on('click', function() {
    $('form#formId').append('<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ url_for('Selec_Assuntos_Inicio', WRotChama = "001", WCodorig = Wformulario.WCPO_Cod_Reuniao ) }}">');
    $('form#formId').submit();
});
```

That said, a potentially better option from both a coding and usability perspective would be to asynchronously load the topic data into the existing page so that you don't have to reload the view at all. That would enable you to avoid needing to do an interim save of the form data.